# How to find the smallest integer $k > 0$ such that the following inequality holds

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I need to find the smallest integer $k>0$ such that the following inequality holds:

$$(1-\frac{1}{365})^k\le\frac{1}{2}$$

The answer is supposedly greater than $200$. How can I find $k$?

Comment: Can you please explain which variant of the "common birthday" problem this inequality comes from?

Comment: It comes from the complement of the "common birthday" problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$k\log(1-\frac{1}{365}) \leq \log\frac12$$

Comment: So 252.6519888. Thanks!

Comment: remember to find the smallest integer.

Comment: It appears to be 252.

Comment: You are very close but that is still not the right answer.

Comment: Note that $\log (1-\frac{1}{365})$ is negative.

Comment: I get k >= 252. But plugging this into the above equations yields a LHS slightly greater than the RHS. However, rounding up the exact answer to 253 yields a LHS slightly less than the RHS. So would the answer be 253?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47185/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-revolution9540).